# Alamofire returning 405 for POST calls

Tags: swift, post, alamofire, http-status-code-405

I'm trying to call a very simple webservice with Alamofire in Swift. The code is as simple as this:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: nil, encoding: .URL)
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                completion(response.result.value as? [String: AnyObject])
            case .Failure:
                completion(nil)
            }
    }
```

This method is always returning a 405 error, but if I test with POSTMAN or other apps the same url with POST, it's working without problems. I've tried everything and cannot find what the problem is, any help please?

PD: All the other GET calls are working without problems. It's only the POST calls which are not working…

Comment: The error says that you a trying to call a method that is not allowed to call, which is likely doesn't exist, could you check the url please?
have you also tried to trace the call from the app with Charles(or some other tool)?

Comment: @fiks The fact is that the method exists, I've tried the same url with Advanced REST client and it's working without problems.

Comment: But did you try to trace the call from the app?

Comment: @fiks Well, I've found that if in Advanced REST client for Chrome I enable XHR it also fails with the same error 405 as in the app. The problem is that the webservice is not mine, so now I must try to guess what is happening…

Comment: @fiks Well, after many, many trials, I've found that the problem was that the url must end with "/". That was causing everything.

Comment: So the url was wrong :) Ok, it's good that you've found the reason.